# Android: Some Share Intents (WeChat, Url2Pdf) not shown right after Customizing

Tags: android, android-intent, wechat

So I'm trying to customize the apps displayed through Intent.ACTION_SEND and it worked out really great except for WeChat and UrlToPDF. Instead of "WeChat" it is  displayed as "Android-System". If I click that, it opens another intent, where the wechat-app is shown right but alone without the other Applications. What have I done wrong?

Here is the code:

```
shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecastStr+" #SunshineApp");

final PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);

ArrayList <String> packageAllowed = new ArrayList();
packageAllowed.add("com.twitter.android");
packageAllowed.add("com.facebook.katana");
packageAllowed.add("com.google.android.gm");
packageAllowed.add("com.whatsapp");
packageAllowed.add("com.evernote");
packageAllowed.add("ch.threema.app");
packageAllowed.add("com.skype.raider");
packageAllowed.add("com.tencent.mm");
packageAllowed.add("com.tencent.mm.ui.tools.ShareToTimeLineUI");

ArrayList <String> packageSum = new ArrayList();

if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
    List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;

        if(packageAllowed.contains(packageName)){
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");

            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            targetedShareIntents.add(intent);
        }
    }

    int size = targetedShareIntents.size();
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(targetedShareIntents.size()-1), "Share");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
}
```

Comment: That was a lot of non-relevant chit-chat please read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set the component name additionally:

```
if(packageAllowed.contains(packageName)){
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");

    // This is new!!!
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name)); 

    intent.setPackage(packageName);
    targetedShareIntents.add(intent);
}
```

Comment: It worked :) thank you very much :)
Can you perhaps explain to me why i had to "setComponent" for some apps? :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I was having a similar issue and this fixed my problem. But marking an answer as solution and giving an upvote will be helpful for others, to determine a correct answer.

Comment: i already mark your answer :) I will give you an upvote by the time i get enough reputation ;) i wont forget but it perhaps will take some time ;) thank you again :)